# Dynamic programming for subsequence metric

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, dynamic-programming

Let $a = a_1, \ldots, a_n, b = b_1, \ldots, b_m$ be sequences of positive integers and for any respective subsequence of length $k$, we consider $\sum_{i=1}^k (a_{x_{i}}-b_{y_{i}})^2$. Given a bound $D$, find the largest $k$ such that there exists subsequences of $a$ and $b$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k (a_{x_{i}}-b_{y_{i}})^2\leq D$ which is polynomial and not proportial w.r.t. $D$.

Heres my attempt:

Define $Opt[i, j, k]$ to be the minimal of the metric of subsequences $a_1, \ldots, a_i$ and $b_1, \ldots b_j$ of length $k$. Then define $$Opt[i, j, k] = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $k =0$}\\ 
\min(Opt[i-1, j-1, k-1]+ (b_i-a_j)^2, Opt[i-1, j-1, k], \min_{1\leq p< i} Opt(p, j, k), \min_{p} Opt(i, p, k) &\text{if $i, j > k$}
\end{cases}$$
Then iterate through $k = 1, \ldots, min(m, n)$.

Im not too sure my answer is correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: The way we tell whether our answer is correct is to prove it correct.  It might also be helpful to check it on a few examples.  I suggest you spend some time on that, then come back and show us how far you got if you have a specific question about that.  Please credit the original source of the problem.  Also, check whether your $y_i$'s should be $x_i$'s.

Comment: Your solution is good and it's correctness is easy to proof, it is done constructively in the same way you built the recurrence. It can be improved (simplified) further if you follow the idea, I take last to elements, or I don't take last element from A, or I don't take last element from B (this covers everything)

Comment: You will get:  opt[i,j,k]=min(opt[i-1,j-1,k-1]+(ai-aj)^2; opt[i-1,j,k]; opt[i,j-1,k])